My service cannot get http request from vector http sink
This is my sink configuration
"sinks": {
        "console_sink": {
            "type": "console",
            "inputs": [
               "vector_http_test_transform"
            ],
            "encoding": {
                "codec": "json"
            }
       },
       "my_http_sink": {
           "type": "http",
           "inputs": [
              "vector_http_test_transform"
           ],
          "method": "post", 
          "encoding": {
               "codec": "json"
           },
           "request": {
               "headers": {
                 "Content-Type": "application/json"
               }
           },
           "uri": "http://myHost:myPort/logs"
       }
    }

My console print like this :
{"file":"/data/logs/n9e-logs/test.log","host":"host.novalocal","message":{"level":"INFO","lineNumber":"21","logDate":"2024-09-24 15:19:14.660963","message":"event(c695d938d8955d triggered) push_queue: rule_id=47 tags:[__name__=mem_used_percent data_group=tok_3dc2a5e1457744379dad ]  2024-09-20 15:19:14.000 ","method":"dispatch/log.go"},"source_type":"file","timestamp":"2024-09-26T02:19:30.405"}

And my sevice get correct request with curl：
curl -X POST http://myHost:myPort/logs -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key":"value"}'

But my service get no http request from vector http sink,what should i do？
